# Identifying which directory a filename comes from

Tags: directory, find, batch

I have a .txt list of filenames which come from two different directories. They come from a server database and share a single characteristic (database flag), but I really need to know which of the 2 directories they come from.

Is there a way to batch process the list to produce a new list which shows which directory the file came from?

I can do it one by one using "find", but the list has about 150 files.

Is it quicker to read about database queries and redo the list myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the files can only be in one of two places, then it's probably more efficient to test each explicitly, e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r f; do 
  if [ -e "dir1/$f" ]; then
    echo "dir1/$f"
  elif [ -e "dir2/$f" ]; then
    echo "dir2/$f"
  else
    echo "$f: not found"
  fi
done < filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `locate` command, which reads a database of all files. The database has to be updated before running `locate`, however.

Here's an example of what one might do

```
$ locate --regex ".*/lightdm.conf$"                                            
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Now, to batch process a list of files , one could use `while read do. . . done < input_file` structure, with `locate` code inside. Something like this:

```
$> cat > file_list.txt                                                         
passwd
lightdm.conf
firefox.desktop

$> while read line ; do                                                        
> locate --regex ".*/$line$"                                                   
> done < file_list.txt                                                         
/etc/passwd
/etc/cron.daily/passwd
/etc/pam.d/passwd
/home/xieerqi/Desktop/cleanup/passwd
/home/xieerqi/Documents/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/passwd
/usr/share/doc/passwd
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/passwd
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Of course this is not the speediest of searches - after all database contains thousands of files , but much speedier than traversing the entire
directory structure with `find`

Comment: you should drop the .* from your regexp, as it doesn't need to try all combinations of it. the remaining (/.... $) is enough and more efficient.